nomenclature position before title page
I have a problem with the position of the nomenclature, it appears at the beginning of the thesis
before the title page
It should appear later list of content

this my preamble
    \documentclass[12pt]{report}
    \usepackage[french,english]{babel}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    
    %\usepackage{times}
    \usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    
    
    \usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{cite}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{pdfpages}
    %\usepackage{subfig}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{pdflscape}
    \usepackage{pdfpages}
    
    \makenomenclature
    
    
    \begin{document}
Table of contents %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}\lhead{\textbf \footnotesize\it{Contents}} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\chead{} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\rhead{}
\pagestyle{fancy}\lfoot{} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\cfoot{} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\rfoot{}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\tableofcontents 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% List of Figures %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of figures}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}\lhead{\textbf \footnotesize\it{List of Figures}} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\chead{} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\rhead{}
\pagestyle{fancy}\lfoot{} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\cfoot{} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\rfoot{}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\listoffigures 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% List of Tables %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of tables}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}\lhead{\textbf \footnotesize\it{List of Tables}} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\chead{} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\rhead{}
\pagestyle{fancy}\lfoot{} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\cfoot{} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\rfoot{}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\listoftables 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% List of Abbreviations %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}\lhead{\textbf \footnotesize\it{}} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\chead{} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\rhead{}
\pagestyle{fancy}\lfoot{} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\cfoot{} 
\pagestyle{fancy}\rfoot{}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
    \printnomenclature

    \nomenclature{$a$}{The number of angels per unit area\nomrefeqpage}%
    \nomenclature{$N$}{The number of angels per needle point\nomrefeq}%
    \nomenclature{$A$}{The area of the needle point\nomrefeq\nomrefpage}%

    \end{document}

